# Between Ana & Apana. What is the terminology for this moment?

Tags: reference-request, anapanasati

Ana (Āna, Āṇā, incoming breath, inhale) & Apana (apāṇa, āpāna, outgoing breath, exhale), there is a moment between them. Or let's say the point switches from incoming breath to outgoing breath.

I can't remember the terminology for this switching point. I believe it exists in the Pali language.

Does anyone know it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Holding breath = [assāsapassāse uparundhitvā](https://5000y.men/?rm.r.150.112.0.0.ass%C4%81sapass%C4%81se%20uparundhitv%C4%81#hl)

Breath's beginning-middle-ending = [Assāsādimajjhapariyosānaṃ](https://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=31&A=4888&h=Ass%C4%81s%C4%81dimajjhapariyos%C4%81na%E1%B9%83#hl)

You may use "Assasapassasanam antaram (in the middle of breath)", but it is "Holding breath" actually. It is abnormal for Anapanassati meditation.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. How do you divide Assāsādimajjhapariyosānaṃ into three words? I could not find from the web.

Comment: Use these to search in pali dictionary....  Assasa/Passasa=Breath in/out. ādi = beginning. majjha = middle. pariyosāna = ending.

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/majjha Great! I found it. I think this is what I had heard before even though this script explains the middle of In-breath and middle of out-breath. My original question was the moment between in-breath AND out-breath. Maybe such a thing doesn't exist in Pali's text. If you find it, let me know!! After all, I am very happy. Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing like that because it is abnormal. Breathing is automatic system without attention. We can hold the breathing or stop breathing, but in normal situation breathing in/out is automatic continuously. You can use "antara" without quoting Pali, however it is weak mindfulness on breathing actually when we can see the space between breathing in/out. That's why we don't have the word to use.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this terminology.

Technically, speaking of 'a moment' only goes as far as the discernment of a beginning & an end.

If one can not discern a beginning & end then one can't talk about it in terms of temporality.

The conditioned changes as it persists and in as far as change is discerned one conceives of a before & after.

> what's called 'mind,' 'intellect,' or 'consciousness' by day and by
> night arises as one thing and ceases as another. Just as a monkey,
> swinging through a forest wilderness, grabs a branch. Letting go of
> it, it grabs another branch. Letting go of that, it grabs another one.
> Letting go of that, it grabs another one. In the same way, what's
> called 'mind,' 'intellect,' or 'consciousness' by day and by night
> arises as one thing and ceases as another. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.061.than.html

> “Sign, in-breath, out-breath, are not object Of a single
> consciousness; By one who knows not these three things Development is
> not obtained. Sign, in-breath, out-breath, are not object Of a single
> consciousness; By one who does know these three things  Development
> can be obtained” (Patis I 170)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, this is not answering my question. Let me know if you have any way to get the targeting Pali terminology!